# error when downloading excel created with phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a problem and I think I have to delete apache cache I have searched for post but I have not been able to solve it. I have installed as a local server XAMPP took time working on a project that works perfectly on the external server and not long ago worked well in the local. in this project I generated an excel docuemnto with PHPexcel I saw myself in the need to update the excel it issued, I made the changes and downloaded the document but when I opened it it said:

"The file you are trying to open has a different format than the one specified by the file extension, check that the file is not corrupted and comes from a trusted source before opening it. Would you like to open the file now?"

I click on open and I see many strange symbols, reversed the changes and keeps sending me the same error not only of this but of others that previously worked well.

Comment: You correctly posted a question, not an answer. How do the file sizes compare? If you open your corrupt Excel file in a plain text editor, do you see any errors? What changes did you make?

Comment: Sorry, edit the question. the file is .php. the change I made was to add a row, but I reversed everything. look for information about it and it's as if you were saving the error in apache cache or php because you already delete the browser cache and still send the same error

Comment: The browser cache shouldn't have any effect on your Excel file being exported. Have you checked your Apache error logs? Did you try any of the suggestions I made?

Comment: If I already did it, following the post that I found and I still have the same problem, there is a post that you can recommend me maybe I'm not doing it right.

Comment: I can't see your code. I have no idea what issue is happening. We're talking about two entirely different environments with an error that you have not specified, there is no magic pill of a solution that I can recommend. I suggest you work on creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Will be happy to help once you provide more information.